# GitHub actions Liquibase update with port forwarding

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, liquibase, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to run a Liquibase update (https://github.com/liquibase-github-actions/update) against my database from a GitHub workflow. The database is an AWS RDS Postgres instance in a private subnet and I'm using a bastion instance to connect to the DB from outside (i.e. my workstation). The setup seems fine, I am able to connect from my station using Putty for example.

My GitHub job has two steps:

```
  - name: Set up port forwarding
    run: |
      mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
      echo "$(aws ssm get-parameter --name ${{ env.BASTION_KEY_SSM_PARAMETER_NAME }} --output text --query 'Parameter.Value')" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      echo "$(ssh-keyscan -p 22 ${{ env.BASTION_FQDN }})" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      # ssh -fNL 15432:${{ env.DATABASE_ENDPOINT }} ubuntu@${{ env.BASTION_FQDN }} -p 22
      ssh -fN -v -L 15432:${{ env.DATABASE_ENDPOINT }} ubuntu@${{ env.BASTION_FQDN }}

  - uses: liquibase-github-actions/update@v4.23.1
    with:
      changelogFile: "./liquibase/changelog.xml"
      url: "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:15432/mydatabase"
      username: ${{ env.DATABASE_USER }}
      password: ${{ env.DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD }}
      logLevel: FINE
```

The first step is responsible for the port forwarding setup, while the second one is supposed to run a Liquibase update against mydatabase.

According to logs, the first steps runs fine and does what I expect it to do:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:15432 forwarded to remote address xyz.abc.***.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 15432.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 15432.
```

However, the second step fails with the following message:

```
[2023-08-24 10:34:43] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:15432/mydatabase with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Connection to 127.0.0.1:15432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
  - Caused by: Connection refused
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:15432/mydatabase with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Connection to 127.0.0.1:15432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

My first reaction was that the SSH setup might be broken in-between the individual step executions, so I've tried adding another step after the first one just to test this:

```
  - name: Set up port forwarding
    run: |
      mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
      echo "$(aws ssm get-parameter --name ${{ env.BASTION_KEY_SSM_PARAMETER_NAME }} --output text --query 'Parameter.Value')" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      echo "$(ssh-keyscan -p 22 ${{ env.BASTION_FQDN }})" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      # ssh -fNL 15432:${{ env.DATABASE_ENDPOINT }} ubuntu@${{ env.BASTION_FQDN }} -p 22
      ssh -fN -v -L 15432:${{ env.DATABASE_ENDPOINT }} ubuntu@${{ env.BASTION_FQDN }}

  - name: Test
    run: |
      lsof -i:15432
```

But this is successful:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     2713 runner    4u  IPv6  27264      0t0  TCP localhost:15432 (LISTEN)
ssh     2713 runner    5u  IPv4  27265      0t0  TCP localhost:15432 (LISTEN)
```

Maybe there is something fundamental that I don't quite get regarding port forwarding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
Having done some additional testing, I realized that my SSH tunnel is set up correctly and works just fine. The problem is that for some reason, the Liquibase action does not have access to the SSH tunnel.

In the end, I've removed the Liquibase action and made the update call using CLI in the first step. If anyone's interested, here's the code that finally worked:

```
- name: Run Liquibase
  run: |
    password=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ${{ env.TF_DATABASE_USER_SECRET }} --output text --query 'SecretString' | jq -r '.password')
    echo "::add-mask::$password"          

    mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
    echo "$(aws ssm get-parameter --name ${{ env.TF_BASTION_KEY_SSM_PARAMETER_NAME }} --output text --query 'Parameter.Value')" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    echo "$(ssh-keyscan -p 22 ${{ env.TF_BASTION_FQDN }})" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    ssh -fN -L 15432:${{ env.TF_DATABASE_ENDPOINT }} ubuntu@${{ env.TF_BASTION_FQDN }}

    wget -O- https://repo.liquibase.com/liquibase.asc | gpg --dearmor > liquibase-keyring.gpg && \
    cat liquibase-keyring.gpg | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/liquibase-keyring.gpg > /dev/null && \
    echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/liquibase-keyring.gpg] https://repo.liquibase.com stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/liquibase.list

    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install liquibase

    export LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_CHANGELOG_FILE=".\liquibase\changelog.xml"
    export LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/mydatabase
    export LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME=${{ env.TF_DATABASE_USER }}
    export LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD=$password
    export LIQUIBASE_LOG_LEVEL=FINE

    liquibase update
```

Comment: What is the value of `env.DATABASE_ENDPOINT`?

Comment: @RobinThomas, thats the private database endpoint, i.e. `xyz.abc.***.rds.amazonaws.com:5432`